# Timeout exception - c# ( wcf )

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, server, timeout

While I'm executing the server method asynchronously, getting this Timeout exception continuously.

"Additional information: 
This request operation sent to http://schemas.microsoft.com/2005/12/ServiceModel/Addressing/Anonymous 
did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).
The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
This may be because the service is still processing the operation or 
because the service was unable to send a reply message.
Please consider increasing the operation timeout 
(by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) 
and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client."

Could someone mention **how to increasing the operation timeout** 
by **casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout** property ?

This is my existing binding (with client) code.

```
    DuplexChannelFactory<IPortal> datafactory;
    NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
    String sURL = "net.tcp://localhost:8002/MyPortal";              
    tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = System.Int32.MaxValue;
    tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = System.Int32.MaxValue;
    datafactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IPortal>(this,tcpBinding, sURL);               
    Portal = datafactory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: tcpBinding has the following timeouts : Close, Open, Receive, and Send

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the link in the error (schemas.microsoft.com etc etc) it serves up:

> Theresource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Why are you looking up MS? It sounds like you've got some config data wrong somewhere. If you search your source for that url, what do you find? Does it look sensible?

Comment: I know the reason for this issue.it is because the method I've call is using large number of parameters.so it simply ask to adjust the maximum timeout by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property.nothing wrong with any other configs.